# React rerenders the page after every login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, twitch

im trying to implement a twitch login on my new web page.
Worked good so far, until the webpage reloads everytime i set the state in the TwitchAuth.tsx.
I thaught that would be completely fine, so now the question:
whats wrong with this tiny code :)

LoginScreen.tsx

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { TwitchAuth } from "../../components/TwitchAuth/TwitchAuth";
import "./LoginScreen.css";

export function LoginScreen() {
  const [code, setCode] = useState<string>("");
  const [id, setId] = useState<string>("");

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h3>Login with Twitch</h3>
        <TwitchAuth code={code} setCode={setCode} id={id} setId={setId} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

TwitchAuth.tsx

```
import { Component } from "react";
import * as crypto from "crypto";

type TwitchProps = {
  id: string;
  code: string;
  setId: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
  setCode: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
};

export class TwitchAuth extends Component<TwitchProps> {
  getLoginUrl = () => {
    const endpoint = process.env.REACT_APP_TWITCH_ID + "oauth2/authorize?";
    this.props.setId(crypto.randomBytes(20).toString("hex"));

    return (
      endpoint +
      new URLSearchParams({
        client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID as string,
        redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000",
        response_type: "code",
        scope: "user:read:email",
        state: this.props.id,
      })
    );
  };

  login = async (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = this.getLoginUrl();
    const query = window.location.search.substring(
      window.location.search.indexOf("code"),
      window.location.search.indexOf("&scope")
    );
    this.props.setCode(query); //this triggers the reload
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.props.code ? (
          <>
            <span>Your Code: {this.props.code}</span>
          </>
        ) : (
          <button onClick={(e) => this.login(e)} className="twitch">
            Login with Twitch
          </button>
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)
Greets

Comment: Setting `window.location.href` to a new value is going to cause a redirect

Comment: Sure its causing a redirect and im also getting Back the Code, the problem is, that after the code state is getting updated, the component is getting reloaded and u need to login again